# a value of type "void *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "TCHAR"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, listbox

I am working on an old C code conversion to C++.  I am in the process of creating a GUI with a list box.  I have an error.  The offending code is :

```
pVarName = calloc(iLength, sizeof(TCHAR));
```

I attempted:

```
pVarName = static_cast<TCHAR*>(calloc(iLength, sizeof(TCHAR)));
```

But, there is still an issue. Help please.  Thank you.

```
// environ.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#include "framework.h"
#include "environ.h"

#define ID_LIST 1
#define ID_TEXT 2

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    static TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT("Environ");
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASS wndclass;

    wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndclass.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName;
    if (!RegisterClass(&wndclass))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("This program requires Windows NT!"),
            szAppName, MB_ICONERROR);
        return 0;
    }
    hwnd = CreateWindow(szAppName, TEXT("Environment List Box"),
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, iCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
void FillListBox(HWND hwndList)
{
    int iLength;

    TCHAR* pVarBlock, * pVarBeg, * pVarEnd, * pVarName;

    pVarBlock = GetEnvironmentStrings(); // Get pointer to environment block
    while (*pVarBlock)
    {
        if (*pVarBlock != '=') // Skip variable names beginning with `=`
        {
            pVarBeg = pVarBlock; // Beginning of variable name
                while (*pVarBlock++ != '='); // Scan until `=`
            pVarEnd = pVarBlock - 1; // Points to `=` sign
            iLength = pVarEnd - pVarBeg; // Length of variable name
            // Allocate memory for the variable name and terminating
            // zero. Copy the variable name and append a zero.


            pVarName = static_cast<TCHAR*>(calloc(iLength + 1, sizeof(TCHAR)));
            // pVarName =(TCHAR *) (  calloc(iLength + 1, sizeof(TCHAR))  );
            // pVarName = (TCHAR*) (TEXT("Two"));


            CopyMemory(pVarName, pVarBeg, iLength * sizeof(TCHAR));
            pVarName[iLength] = '\0' ;
                // Put the variable name in the list box and free memory.
                SendMessage(hwndList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)pVarName);
            free(pVarName);
        }
        while (*pVarBlock++ != '\0') ; // Scan until terminating zero
    }
    FreeEnvironmentStrings(pVarBlock);
}
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HWND hwndList, hwndText;
    int iIndex, iLength, cxChar, cyChar;
    TCHAR* pVarName, * pVarValue;
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        cxChar = LOWORD(GetDialogBaseUnits());
        cyChar = HIWORD(GetDialogBaseUnits());
        // Create listbox and static text windows.
        hwndList = CreateWindow(TEXT("listbox"), NULL,
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LBS_STANDARD,
            cxChar, cyChar * 3,
            cxChar * 16 + GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVSCROLL),
            cyChar * 5,
            hwnd, (HMENU)ID_LIST,
            (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE),
            NULL);
        hwndText = CreateWindow(TEXT("static"), NULL,
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_LEFT,
            cxChar, cyChar,
            GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN), cyChar,
            hwnd, (HMENU)ID_TEXT,
            (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE),
            NULL);
        FillListBox(hwndList);
        return 0;
    case WM_SETFOCUS:
        SetFocus(hwndList);
        return 0;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == ID_LIST && HIWORD(wParam) == LBN_SELCHANGE)
        {
            // Get current selection.
            iIndex = SendMessage(hwndList, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);
            iLength = SendMessage(hwndList, LB_GETTEXTLEN, iIndex, 0) + 1;


            pVarName = static_cast<TCHAR*>(calloc(iLength, sizeof(TCHAR)));
            //pVarName = (TCHAR *) (calloc(iLength, sizeof(TCHAR)));
            //pVarName = (TCHAR *) (TEXT("One and Two"));



            SendMessage(hwndList, LB_GETTEXT, iIndex, (LPARAM)pVarName);
            // Get environment string.
            iLength = GetEnvironmentVariable(pVarName, NULL, 0);


            pVarValue = (TCHAR *) (calloc(iLength, sizeof(TCHAR)));


            GetEnvironmentVariable(pVarName, pVarValue, iLength);
            // Show it in window.
            SetWindowText(hwndText, pVarValue);
            free(pVarName);
            free(pVarValue);
        }
        return 0;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: What's the full verbatim error message of `pVarName = static_cast<TCHAR*>(calloc(iLength, sizeof(TCHAR)));`?

Comment: wntdll.pdb not loaded.    environ.exe has triggered a breakpoint.  comment: seems like a core dump to me.

Comment: Why didn't you mention this errors in your question? Please edit your question and add all necessary information.

Comment: Now I know to mention the error in my question.

Comment: Please describe the problem. A core dump means your code can be compiled and you started the program. What's the stack trace of the crash? How do you expect others to help you without any valuable information? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: compiles and runnable.  stack trace?  I work at a company where programs are installed or updated through IT.  And it seems to me I require a software to inspect the stack trace.  Unless you can guide me to stack trace viewer on Visual Studio.  Otherwise, it will take time to locate a stack trace viewer and install.

Comment: Why did you choose _"a value of type “void *” cannot be assigned to an entity of type “TCHAR”"_ as the title of the question if you already fixed it before you asked the question? Please update the title. I don't know Visual Studio's debugger but every debugger I know can stop at a crash and show you the stack trace at this point. Maybe this can help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/viewing-the-call-stack-in-visual-studio

Comment: It is not fixed.  I am getting an error.  A "fix" generates a core dump.

Comment: Stack trace in Visual Studio is usually in the bottom right of the debug screen. Run the program with the debugger and when it keels over an dies, accept the offer to debug. Then consult the stack to gather information.

Comment: That are two completely unrelated problems. The first problem was a compile error because you didn't cast the pointer. It's very likely that this fix doesn't cause this runtime error.

Comment: Stack Trace line 82  "environ.exe has triggered a breakpoint" : FreeEnvironmentStrings(pVarBlock);

Comment: You are changing `pVarBlock` and after the change you free the address `pVarBlock` is pointing to. That's a bad idea.

Comment: Great. You found the problem.  What is your recommendation, sir?

Answer (score 2):

You are receiving environment strings with

```
pVarBlock = GetEnvironmentStrings();
```

and later you correctly free them with

```
FreeEnvironmentStrings(pVarBlock);
```

But the problem is that you change the pointer between the two lines. You can copy the pointer and work with the copy:

```
TCHAR* pVarBeg, * pVarEnd, * pVarName;

TCHAR *pVarBlockCopy = GetEnvironmentStrings(); // Get pointer to environment block
TCHAR *pVarBlock = pVarBlockCopy;
while (*pVarBlock)
{
    if (*pVarBlock != '=') // Skip variable names beginning with `=`
    {
        pVarBeg = pVarBlock; // Beginning of variable name
            while (*pVarBlock++ != '='); // Scan until `=`
        pVarEnd = pVarBlock - 1; // Points to `=` sign
        iLength = pVarEnd - pVarBeg; // Length of variable name
        // Allocate memory for the variable name and terminating
        // zero. Copy the variable name and append a zero.

        pVarName = static_cast<TCHAR*>(calloc(iLength + 1, sizeof(TCHAR)));
        // pVarName =(TCHAR *) (  calloc(iLength + 1, sizeof(TCHAR))  );
        // pVarName = (TCHAR*) (TEXT("Two"));

        CopyMemory(pVarName, pVarBeg, iLength * sizeof(TCHAR));
        pVarName[iLength] = '\0' ;
            // Put the variable name in the list box and free memory.
            SendMessage(hwndList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)pVarName);
        free(pVarName);
    }
    while (*pVarBlock++ != '\0') ; // Scan until terminating zero
}
FreeEnvironmentStrings(pVarBlockCopy);
```